# .forEach index exceeds length of array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm playing around on CodeFights and I'm still in the process of learning javascript. I'm doing one of their basic challenges and I've hit a snag.

I don't want a solution but rather an explanation for what's happening with my code. The purpose of the code is to simply return the highest product of any two adjacent elements in the array. I think that the last time the code runs the nextNum variable is set to NaN as it's an index that doesn't exist. I guess I'm confused why my code still changes highestProduct to 18 when NaN != 1 as far as I'm aware and I don't get where the 18 would even come from unless it started looping through again. Any help greatly appreciated.

Here it is:

```js
function adjacentElementsProduct(inputArray) {
    let highestProduct;
    inputArray.forEach(function(loopNum) {
        let nextNum = inputArray.indexOf(loopNum) + 1;
        let newProduct = inputArray[nextNum] * loopNum;
        if (nextNum === 1) {
            highestProduct = newProduct;
        } else if (newProduct > highestProduct) {
            highestProduct = newProduct;
        }
        console.log(highestProduct);
    })
    return highestProduct;
}
let testArr = [3, 6, -2, -5, 7, 3]
console.log(adjacentElementsProduct(testArr));
```

Comment: `function (loopNum, index) { let nextNum = index + 1; ...`

Comment: @GeorgeJempty: The OP knows that (and called it out).

Comment: +1 @PatrickRoberts beat me to it, also when you are on the last item, there wont be another item in the array to compare

Comment: @Sam: The OP knows that and called it out.

Comment: `nextNum` won't ever be `NaN`. It may be "out of bounds" (last index + 1) but in this special case, this also won't happen because the first and last element in the array are the same, hence `.indexOf(loopNum)` will return `0` for the last element in the array (hint: `nextNum` will be `1` for the last element)

Comment: @PatrickRoberts: Because it was wrong. :-) I've posted a new one that's (hopefully!) not wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's going back to 18 because of this line:

```
let nextNum = inputArray.indexOf(loopNum) + 1;
```

On the last loop, `loopNum` is `3`. There are two `3`s in the array, one at the beginning and another at the end. When you get to the end, `indexOf` finds the one at the beginning, returning index 0, which you add one to and assign to `nextNum`, making it `1`. That means this kicks in:

```
if (nextNum === 1) {
    highestProduct = newProduct;
```

...and sets `highestProduct` back to 18 even though it was 21 on the previous pass.

As [Patrick Roberts pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48568026/foreach-index-exceeds-length-of-array/48568124#comment84132270_48568026), you don't need to discover the index, because the `forEach` callback receives it as a second argument. And as you indicated, you realize you need to stop one earlier in the array.

So with those two minor changes:

```js
function adjacentElementsProduct(inputArray) {
    let highestProduct;
    inputArray.forEach(function(loopNum, index) {            // ***
        let nextNum = index + 1;                             // ***
        if (nextNum < inputArray.length) {                   // ***
            let newProduct = inputArray[nextNum] * loopNum;
            if (nextNum === 1) {
                highestProduct = newProduct;
            } else if (newProduct > highestProduct) {
                highestProduct = newProduct;
            }
            console.log(highestProduct);
        }
    })
    return highestProduct;
}
let testArr = [3, 6, -2, -5, 7, 3]
console.log(adjacentElementsProduct(testArr));
```

---

**By far**, the best way to understand something like this is to use the debugger built into your IDE or browser to step through it, statement by statement, looking at the values of variables and such as you go.

Comment: Looks pretty much the same as the last revision of your previous answer

Comment: @PatrickRoberts: Well, there was that whole NaN tangent... :-) With his `indexOf` call, we never got into NaNs... Basically, when I realized my explanation was wrong, I deleted it, figured out why my explanation was wrong and what was really happening, and figured A) It had been a while, and B) The crux of the matter really was your comment. So posted a new CW so as not to FGITW...

Answer (score 0):

Your code is going through the loop and when it reaches the last element of the array it pulls the next element for the product and goes back to the index of 1. Here's the explanation.

```
nextNum: 1 newProduct: 18 highestProduct: undefined
inputArray[1]: 6 loopNum: 3
nextNum: 2 newProduct: -12 highestProduct: 18
inputArray[2]: -2 loopNum: 6
nextNum: 3 newProduct: 10 highestProduct: 18
inputArray[3]: -5 loopNum: -2
nextNum: 4 newProduct: -35 highestProduct: 18
inputArray[4]: 7 loopNum: -5
nextNum: 5 newProduct: 21 highestProduct: 18
inputArray[5]: 3 loopNum: 7
nextNum: 1 newProduct: 18 highestProduct: 21
inputArray[1]: 6 loopNum: 3
18
```

Answer (score 0):

For I came up with something very close to @T.J.Crowder 's answer, I stopped posting mine though taking the chance to go even one step further.

Since the main issue had to be solved with using a better comparison and `index` as 2nd callback parameter, I want to point to a more suitable array iterator method than `forEach` for the given case is ... [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce). With this method the logic within a customized callback function can be achieved with better readable and less code.

The following provided example code should not be seen as an answer to the OP but more as an example of what can be done with refactoring and using better suitable tools ...

```js
function collectMaximumAdjacentElementsProduct (maxProduct, number, idx, numberList) {
    var
        nextNumber = numberList[idx + 1];

    if (typeof nextNumber !== 'undefined') {
        maxProduct = Math.max(maxProduct, (number * nextNumber));
    }
    return maxProduct;
}

var arr = [3, 6, -2, -5, 7, 3];
var num = arr.reduce(collectMaximumAdjacentElementsProduct, Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY)

console.log('collectMaximumAdjacentElementsProduct', arr, ':', num);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```